# How URL works? And what is the relation with GET and POST?

Tags: url, post, get

I have question, basic question I guess. But its important for me to learn more about web application.

I've ever seen a url with there are other words. for example:
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Setapak&mode=xml

there is q=setapak&mode=xml. what it means?
and what relationship with GET or POST?

when I try to create a simple page such which the code are:

```
    <?lc
put $_GET['number'] into number

put number
?>
```

and I run the url on the browser: livecode/nana/url.lc?number=1

it shows nothing. So I get confuse. Can anyone explain to me?
Thank you..

Comment: There are lot of blogs and sites which describe GET and POST methods. You can refer <http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp>

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get>

Comment: how about mode=xml? what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use single quotes in LC. use normal quotes around "number", and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Get will transfer you Parameter Using URL 
all parameters will add to the URL `?number=1` this is one such example. it will carry number variable with value 1.

Post transfer parameters by attaching them to HTTP message body. Refer below link and you can get a good understanding about that.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: and then, why the browser can't show the number after I get it by $_GET['number']?

Comment: what is that language??  php??

Comment: no, Livecode.. and also, how about mode=xml? what it means?

Comment: xml is the value mode is the variable.